# jsTree : Append child node dynamically

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using below code while page load to generate a tree using [jsTree](http://jstree.com/).

```
  $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
          'core': {
             'themes': {
                        'name': 'proton',
                        'responsive': true
                        },
             'data': results,
             "check_callback" : true
          }
  });
```

All is working fine and results array is showing as tree.I want to add /append dynamically child nodes while clicking on few of the nodes in this static tree.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `children` property of a particular node to `true` then the node is rendered as closed, and when the node is expanded then `core.data.data` and `core.data.url` functions are called (this is assuming you are using AJAX).

See the docs for using AJAX http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/

Alternatively you can supply a function for `core.data` which is what is called to load the tree, and any nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the jsTree API, you can make use of these below.

`get_children_dom (obj)`

`draw_children(node)private`

Learn how to fetch a single child node and draw it.

Comment: thanks seoyoochan, I want to append multiple node ( lazy load from a different data set /array) to my static tree ( generated on page load)